# COULD NOT CREATE SSL/TLS SECURE CHANNEL: Client certificates, TomCat and .Net

Tags: ssl, .net-4.0, client-certificates

I am having the same issue with client certificates that many people have reported, but none of the solutions I've seen have worked for me. I have a client I wrote in VB.Net (using VS 2010 and .Net framework 4.0) that needs to connect to a web service running on Apache Tomcat/5.0.27. It works fine with SSL when client certificates are not required, but as soon as client certificates are required, it fails with “THE REQUEST WAS ABORTED: COULD NOT CREATE SSL/TLS SECURE CHANNEL”

Testing it with Internet Explorer (8, 9 and 10, on XP and Win7x32), when SSL is enabled (configured on Tomcat by setting sslProtocol="TLS" secure="true" scheme="https" in the system.xml file), but client certificates are disabled (clientAuth="false"), IE is happy after the CA certificate and the server certificate are installed on the client PC. (IE will complain without the certificates, but you can tell it to ignore the warning. When the certificates are installed, it connects without any warnings.) When client certificates are required (clientAuth="true"), IE will not connect. After I import the client certificate file, it still does not connect. IE shows that the client file is installed, and it shows the certificate is ok and it trusts the CA, but it shows it in what seems to be the wrong store: Intermediate Certificate Authorities, and client authentication is not ticked under Purpose. The MMC certificates snap-in shows the client certificate is in the Personal - Current User store.

The certificate was issued to us by the owners of the web service, so in theory it has to work. The properties look ok, and the purpose shows "All application policies".

I need to get this to work with my .Net client. I use a Web Reference to create the connection to the web service. I set PreaAuthenticate=True, and attach the certificate file to the web reference, and can see it attached in the IDE. Using Network Monitor, I can see that the server sends certificates to the client (in two large packets), but the client doesn't seem to send any back to the server.

I have tried various recommendations, e.g. setting ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true and 
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3, but this makes no difference.

I have disabled firewalls and proxy servers, so nothing should be blocking the traffic.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it turns out there is a problem with the certificate they supplied, or it is somehow incompatible with the client. I found instructions on using OpenSsl to create a certificate, and it works with their server. They used java's keytool to make the certificate, so either it creates an incompatible certificate, or they didn't use the right procedure, and the procedure I used with OpenSsl is the correct one.

The steps in OpenSsl are to create a private key file (client.key), create a certificate request (client.req), sign the key (client.pem) then export it (client.pfx).